# Unity, компонент Button не видит функции в скрипте

Tags: c#, unity3d, button

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно для кнопки задать функцию, но юнити ничего не видет, как будто это пустой файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В поле нужно сам объект перетащить, на котором скрипт player висит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, я 3 часа не мог понять что такое а тут ты, огромное спасибо)